# Copying code and creating build by executing shell script on MacOS(Ventura) through API fails to copy the code due to permission errors

Tags: android, ios, typescript, shell, shellexecute

I have an api which executes a shell script on a MacOS(Ventura) server. The script starts the execution without issues.
The script's function is to copy the code of an iOS and Android app and create build. But while creating builds for both iOS and Android , the Xcode and android commands have to access different folders and files like Derived Data folder , and on Android gradle folder. Also have to create cache folders.But it fails to access those due to permission error.
When the same script is run directly by the MacOS user it works perfectly fine but whenever it is executed through the API, the build process fails.

Here is the code, through which the script execution is triggered :

```
shell_exec('xyz.sh');
```

Some of the errors include :

Also the copied source code when opened in Xcode gives error to UNLOCK the project file and when unlocking it says "You do not have the permission to edit"

*cp: /Users/username/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/5f15678-6bb8-4d5-adb-ad51b97fe926.mobileprovision: Permission denied*

*Couldn't create workspace arena folder '/var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Motto_Mobile_New-gxwkwneokwqfthcucsmectjkjgqq': You don’t have permission to save the file “Motto_Mobile_New-gxwkwneokwqfthcucsmectjkjgqq” in the folder “DerivedData”.*

*Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.3.3-bin/6a41zxkdtcxs8rphpq6y0069z/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip.lck (Permission denied)*

Like I wrote above, all works fine when the script is run directly on the System using the terminal.

Please let me know if there is any solution.

EDIT - Also found that this line :

```
echo "$BUILD_KEYCHAIN_PW" | sudo -S xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

when executed gives this error :

***Password:Sorry, try again.
Password:
sudo: no password was provided
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt***

The above error is seen in the logfile generated.

Comment: From what I can see, xyz.sh has been started, because the `cp` error most likely was produced from inside the shell script. Perhaps putting a `set -x` inside the script would reveal some insight?

Comment: @user1934428 - Yes you are right. It does start , but still it is not able to access or create some folder/files which creating the build.
But when I directly execute this script, everything works fine.

Comment: Whell, if you run a program from different environments, you can't automatically expect that it will behave in the same way, can you? Since you concluded that xyz.sh has been started, the error must occur inside the script. From the line you found, I would first check what is stored in BUILD_KEYCHAIN_PW, and whether the same `sudo` is run from the script and from the command line.

Comment: @user1934428
the same line of code as well as the whole script runs fine on the terminal of that same machine. In the BUILD_KEYCHAIN_PW , the password for the system has been saved.

Comment: How did you verify that the variable has the correct password in the error case?

Comment: @user1934428 - I executed the same line in the terminal with the same password and it was executed successfully. Infact the same script worsks perfectly with the same variable when executed locally on the same machine. So, no need to verify anything.

Comment: How do you know that it was really the **same** variable, and not another variable with the same name but different value? Honestly, debugging works by verifying what we BELIEVE is correct,  I think that's the idea of the word "to verify" ....